# Feynman-like diagrams for photon/electron interaction and electron recollision

Tags: feynman-diagrams, laser-interaction

Feynman diagram is a useful and powerful tool to represent path integrals. But, most of its applications seem to be focused on relativistic particule creation/annihilation.

As far as I can understand Feynman diagrams, it could also be used for electron/photon and electron/electron interaction. More specifically, I would be interested to use this approach to describe ioniszation and electron recollision driven by Intense Laser Field (electron/electron interaction with emission of energetic photon). Usually, many photons are absorbed.

How would you describe a process like ionisation -> free propagation -> recollision using Feynman diagram? 
Have you ever heard of diagrammatic representation of this process or other non-relativistic particule interaction? Which comprehensive reference on that topic would you suggest me?

Comment: It is widely used in condensed matter theory. There electrons have non-relativistic dispersions and Coulomb interactions. You can also deal with interactions of electrons with phonons in the same formalism.

Comment: In my case, I consider isolated molecules interacting with a high density of photon. Path integral formalism is usually not advantageous in that context. But as I consider dynamical events, the path integrals gives interesting insight of the physical process and allow ones to easily possible events and their relative importance.

Comment: [Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical Physics](http://www.amazon.com/Methods-Quantum-Theory-Statistical-Physics/dp/0486632288) by Abrikosov, Gorkov and Dzyaloshinsky is an ever-relevant classic of Russian-language literature. I don’t know if the English translation is any good, though.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the ionisation-recollision processes etc. will remain coherent (so that you really need to sum amplitudes), or maybe due to decoherent processes just probabilistic summation will be necessary?

Comment: As aparticle physicist  I take exception to your " But, most of its applications seem to be focused on relativistic particule creation/annihilation. "  Feyman diagrams are extensively usedto calculate expectations for  all scattering experiments. and also for decay probabilities. The standard model of physics has been extensively  used for modeling LHC physics, and all calculations are based on feynman diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that Feynman diagrams do not contain any "new physics" and neither must they necessarily be related to path integrals , they are just a visually convenient way to categorize the many terms from the Wick contractions in the pertrubative Dyson expansion.

That being said, when you want to describe electron electron interaction with a "background" of photons, where photons only interact with very high numbers at a time, you might find it useful to study the External field approximation techniques, where the electromagnetic field is treated at the classical level as a background field (see Weinberg Vol I, 13.6). This is particularly useful for deriving the lamb shift for example.

Comment: In my mind, Dyson perturbative expansion is closely related to path integrals. At least, my goal is to describe the possible paths (for example: direct ionixation, ionization induced by recollision, ionization with inelastic scattering, etc.) using Feynman-like diagrams.